# RPI4 missing 'pieeprom.bin' file?

Tags: pi-4, bootloader, pi4-eeprom

I'm trying to edit the bootloader config following the rpi official instructions (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md). However, when I try `rpi-eeprom-config pieeprom.bin`, I get  "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pieeprom.bin'". I get the same error for any command that includes "pieeprom.bin". Is this a file that I need to create?

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the first line of the instructions is

```
# Copy the EEPROM image of interest from 
/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/
to pieeprom.bin`
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought the line below `rpi-eeprom-config pieeprom.bin > bootconf.txt` would make that copy. How would I copy the image to `pieeprom.bin`?

Comment: https://www.hostinger.co.uk/tutorials/linux-commands